# Changing default settings for Cmake configuration in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

In the settings for CLion, CMake only appears in **Build, Execution, Deployment** under project specific settings.  It does not exist under **Default Settings**.  Is there a way I can specify a universal CMake configuration such that it is available to all projects by default for current and all future projects unless specified otherwise?

For example let's say I want to set the **Generation path** of all projects to a default location of build.  Instead of manually editing the project settings for each project to include that, is there a workaround to set that as the default?

Please try to provide a solution that will only affect a local environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only starting from CLion 2019.3 there is [ability](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1887) to configure CMake defaults.

It will affect all new projects (without `.idea` config directory).

[image]

You can specify default build types/toolchains, CMake options, generation path [etc](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2019/10/clion-2019-3-eap-coverage-cmake-defaults-lldb/#cmake_defaults).
Also there is pretty nice macro `$PROJECT_NAME$`.

Comment: It is now in `File | New Projects Setup | Settings for New Projects...`.